# Migrating data from a document library to list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2007, sharepoint-designer

We have the following scenario.

1. Large project requests come into a SharePoint document library, where we are using metadata from the word document to populate fields (costing, requester, acceptance status).
2. We also have projects which are much smaller that we do not require a formal document but we require a couple fields such as dates and requester.
3. Data from the small project and large projects needs to be collated, so we can track status and do some analysis on projects completed to date.

In order to have use across the company we need to make the data entry simple.  Entering a new line into a list is something we can get managers to do, but filling out a document (even if it is only a step or two more) is pushing it.

I'm wondering if there is a way to merge periodically transfer the 'large projects' which are accepted into a document list.  I'm open to other implementation ideas within SharePoint 2007, including Designer-based solutions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To be honest it depends on what you mean by "merge" the data.

SharePoint Designer 2007 (and later versions) has a feature called "linked data sources" which you can find by opening your site, clicking Data View, then Manage Data Sources. On the right hand pane if you expand linked data sources you can see that you can add a new linked data source.

This will allow you to merge data from two lists and you can then create your own data view on an application page with that data source. Unfortunately when you display the data source, you lose all your fancy features such as sorting and filtering on the fly. This data view is made possible by some nice XSL transformation which you will need to try to replicate to achieve this.

You may have success using the standard XSL templates for a standard data view but I have never tested this on a linked data source. If you go this far, please let me know the outcome.

Comment: Hi Robert,  I did exactly this for a different project and had adequate results.  Like you said, you lose all the stock filtering and sorting.


In this case, I'm not sure if that would work as I'm trying to only grab the approved major projects (which are in a document library) and merge those with a list.

Also, thanks for the response!